# Javascript Split regex escaped delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'M trying to split a value only if the delimiter is not escaped.

I have read many question on StackOverflow on this but nothing works for me.

I have this value:

```
 InvalidMsg(this,'error with this caracter \', please change your value.');
```

the keyword here is: \'

I want to get the error message so I try something like:

```
var str = "InvalidMsg(this,'error with this caracter \', please change your value.');";
matches = str.match(/([^']|\\')+/g);
alert(matches[1]); //error with this caracter
```

I need to get the full message..

the full message is:

```
 error with this caracter ', please change your value
```

any idea?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regex should work for you to capture your string from `'` to `'` ignoring all escaped quotes on the way:

```
/'((?:[^\\]*\\')*[^']*)'/
```

#### [Online regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vI3vM9/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try below regex and find the result in the matched groups using *Non-capturing group*

```
(.*)(?:,')(.*)\\('.*)(?:'\);)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/fN0xV5/2)

Input:

```
InvalidMsg(this,'error with this caracter \', please change your value.');
```

Match

1. `InvalidMsg(this`
2. `error with this caracter`
3. `', please change your value.`

Sample code:

```
var re = /(.*)(?:,')(.*)\\('.*)(?:'\);)/g;
var str = 'InvalidMsg(this,\'error with this caracter \', please change your value.\');';
var subst = '$2$3';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

output:

```
error with this caracter ', please change your value.
```